# How do i control what socket thread I want to connect to in a asychronous reverse server python?

Tags: python, multithreading

Good evening, This is my 1st time on this site, I have been programming a python based user monitoring system for my work for the past 3 months and I am almost done with my 1st release. However I have run into a problem controlling what computer I want to connect to.

If i run the two sample code I put in this post I can receive the client and send commands to client with the server, but only one client at a time, and the server is dictating which client I can send to  and which one is next. I am certain the problem is "server side but I am not sure how to fix the problem and a Google search does not turn up anyone having tried this.

I have attached both client and server base networking code in this post.

client:

```
import asyncore
import socket
import sys
do_restart = False
class client(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port=8000):
        serv = open("srv.conf","r")
        host = serv.read()
        serv.close()
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((host, port))
    def writable(self):
        return 0
    def handle_connect(self):
        pass           
    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(4096)
        #Rest of code goes here 
serv = open("srv.conf","r")
host = serv.read()
serv.close()
request = client(host)
asyncore.loop()
```

server:

```
import asyncore
import socket
import sys
class  soc(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, port=8000):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)   
        self.port = port
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind(('', port))
        self.listen(5)
    def handle_accept(self):
        channel, addr = self.accept()
        while 1:
            j = raw_input(addr)
            #Rest of my code is here
server = soc(8000)
asyncore.loop()
```

Comment: What is the goal of the `raw_input` here?

Comment: raw_input is supposed to take user input for a series of possible administrative commands such as "Shutdown" "nano" "logoff" and then in that same def is a if then else sequence tat figures out what each command is.

Comment: But what I don't understand ... are the `raw_inputs` just supposed to stack up on the server? So you will be watching the server and suddenly an input starts with an address...Then you issue some return value and another pops up from some other client? Basically you cannot synchronously call `raw_input` and wait on the results, using this approach.

Comment: It displays one IP at a tome and allows me to send a command to one connected IP at a time. after I send the command, it switches to a differnet connnected IP and I have no way of controlling it,

Comment: Thats the goal you are trying to achieve here, or what you currently are seeing?

Comment: that what I am seeing at this time. I need to be able to control which IP I connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fast and dirty idea that I threw together.

The use of `raw_input` has been replaced with another dispatcher that is asyncore compatable, referencing this [other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312977/asyncore-loop-and-raw-input-problem)

And I am expanding on the answer given by @user1320237 to defer each new connection to a new dispatcher.

You wanted to have a single command line interface that can send control commands to any of the connected clients. That means you need a way to switch between them. What I have done is created a dict to keep track of the connected clients. Then we also create a set of available commands that map to callbacks for your command line.

This example has the following:

- `list`:  list current clients
- `set <client>`:  set current client
- `send <msg>`: send a msg to the current client

**server.py**

```
import asyncore
import socket
import sys
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary


class Soc(asyncore.dispatcher):

    CMDS = {
        'list': 'cmd_list',
        'set': 'cmd_set_addr',
        'send': 'cmd_send',
    }

    def __init__(self, port=8000):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)  

        self._conns = WeakValueDictionary()
        self._current = tuple()

        self.port = port
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind(('', port))
        self.listen(5)

        self.cmdline = Cmdline(self.handle_input, sys.stdin)
        self.cmdline.prompt()


    def writable(self):
        return False

    def handle_input(self, i):
        tokens = i.strip().split(None, 1)
        cmd = tokens[0]
        arg = ""
        if len(tokens) > 1:
            arg = tokens[1]

        cbk = self.CMDS.get(cmd)
        if cbk:
            getattr(self, cbk)(arg)

        self.cmdline.prompt(self._addr_to_key(self._current))

    def handle_accept(self):
        channel, addr = self.accept()
        c = Conn(channel)
        self._conns[self._addr_to_key(addr)] = c

    def _addr_to_key(self, addr):
        return ':'.join(str(i) for i in addr)

    def cmd_list(self, *args):
        avail = '\n'.join(self._conns.iterkeys())
        print "\n%s\n" % avail

    def cmd_set_addr(self, addr_str):
        conn = self._conns.get(addr_str)
        if conn:
            self._current = conn.addr

    def cmd_send(self, msg):
        if self._current:
            addr_str = self._addr_to_key(self._current)
            conn = self._conns.get(addr_str)
            if conn:
                conn.buffer += msg         


class Cmdline(asyncore.file_dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, cbk, f):
        asyncore.file_dispatcher.__init__(self, f)
        self.cbk = cbk

    def prompt(self, msg=''):
        sys.stdout.write('%s > ' % msg)
        sys.stdout.flush()        

    def handle_read(self):
        self.cbk(self.recv(1024))


class Conn(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  
        self.buffer = ""

    def writable(self):
        return len(self.buffer) > 0

    def handle_write(self):
        self.send(self.buffer)
        self.buffer = ''

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(4096)
        print self.addr, '-', data


server = Soc(8000)
asyncore.loop()
```

Your main server is now never blocking on `stdin`, and always accepting new connections. The only work it does is the command handling which should either be a fast operation, or signals the connection objects to handle the message.

Usage:

```
# start the server
# start 2 clients
> 
> list

127.0.0.1:51738
127.0.0.1:51736

> set 127.0.0.1:51736
127.0.0.1:51736 >
127.0.0.1:51736 > send foo

# client 127.0.0.1:51736 receives "foo"
```

Comment: That worked brilliantly! All I have to do is add encryption features and port a couple of complex commands.Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To me

```
    while 1:
        j = raw_input(addr)
```

seems to be the problem:
you only accept a socket an then do something with it until end.

You should create e new dispatcher for every client connecting

```
class  conn(asyncore.dispatcher):
     ...
     def handle_read(self):
         ...

class  soc(asyncore.dispatcher):
     def handle_accept(self):
         ...
         c = conn()
         c.set_socket(channel)
```

Asyncore will call you back for every read operation possible.

Asyncore uses only one thread. This is its strength. every dispatcher that has a socket is called one after an other with those `handle_*` functions.

Comment: I think this is a good start to a suggestion, but ultimately the `raw_input` needs to be addressed as its still not allowed to be used. It will just end up blocking again.

Comment: it is not only the raw_input. I fear the while loop itself does operations on the `channel`. It should not do read on the `channel`.

Comment: Ya that is true as well. Anything that is happening in the while loop should be fast/non-blocking so that it can keep accepting connections. This is the gotcha with async communication. Gotta keep everything using callbacks.